# Android Studio Canary 4 App won't run unless you update Google Play Services

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I have updated Emulators from SDK manager and created new Virtual Device. Still having trouble with running my app from Android Studio using Google Maps API. Please help.

UPDATE:

I have fixed it by installing a Virtual Device which is 1 API lower (API 25) using x86_64. This installs the necessary Intel Atom System Image. Now I can see the Goodle Map in the emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two ways
1: https://medium.com/@dai_shi/installing-google-play-services-on-an-android-studio-emulator-fffceb2c28a1
2: use genymotion (requires virtual box) link- https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: As a beginner, I would prefer to use the Android emulator. Thanks for answering anyways.

Comment: the first method is for android emulator.